# Gem located on github don't require gems from rubygems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, git, github, rubygems

I have this line in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'gem_name', '1.0.27', :git => "git@github.com:company/gem_name.git"
```

gem_name is a gem that I built stored on github, and in one of the gem code files I wrote:

```
require 'cssmin'
```

(I have more gem requirements in the gem code files).

When I run bundle in my app, everything works fine and gem_name is installed properly 
But when I run `rails s` I get this error:

> cannot load such file -- cssmin

Do you know why I cant require gems from rubygems in my gem code files that are stored on github?

Comment: where `cssmin` file is located?

Comment: cssmin is a gem located on rubygems

Comment: have you included cssmin in your `.gemspec`?

Comment: I need to include all the gems I need in a .gemspec/Gemfile? I can't use require ?

Comment: you can either include needed gem into Gemfile or use command line `gem install gemname`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When writing your own gem, you should include all its requirements in a `.gemspec` file. That way, the `gem` program can make sure it installs all the dependencies when the user runs `gem install gem_name`, and your code won't crash when it runs the `require 'my_dependency'` line.

If you want to use other libraries in your code, you need both parts. The Gemspec file makes sure dependencies are installed; the `require` statement loads it when your code runs.

In this case, you should use the [`add_runtime_dependency` method](http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/#add_runtime_dependency) in your Gemspec. Something like this:

```
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  # Required attributes omitted
  s.add_runtime_dependency('cssmin') # If you don't care which version is installed
  s.add_runtime_dependency('nokogiri', '>= 1.2') # If you want a version greater than or equal to 1.2
  s.add_runtime_dependency('kaminari', '~> 1.1') # If you want a version between 1.1 and 1.9.
end
```

You can read more about declaring dependencies in [the Rubygems documentation](http://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/#declaring-dependencies).